# Jquery only working on Chrome?

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have been working on a project for some time, but never tested it on firefox until now, and found out none of my jquery works on firefox. Only chrome. Can anybody tell me why it's acting this way? Is it a syntax error? Is it something to do with incompatibility of jquery with firefox?

```
$('#dropmenutitle').click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#dropmenu').fadeToggle('fast');
    $('body').click(function () {
        $('#dropmenu').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});

$('#popboxtitle').click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#popboxtop').fadeToggle('fast');
    $('body').click(function () {
        $('#popboxtop').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

That is my code, and I am using jquery 1.7.1

Comment: would help if you explained what the problem is...

Comment: I am trying to make two different divs that were designed to be popups to popup when a link (trigger) has been clicked. currently, the popups can only work on chrome, but not on firefox. clicking the triggers doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your events, `event` does not exist.  You need to put it in the parameter list.

```
$('#dropmenutitle').click(function (event) {
});

$('#popboxtitle').click(function (event) {
});
```

Comment: thank you SO MUCH! i completely forgot about that! I'll keep this in mind the next time i work with jquery! Thanks again!

Comment: I want to point out, why your code was working on chrome, "event" is internally provided by IE and Chrome, but it is not there in Firefox irrespective of you define in parameter or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue, but in my case I was wiring key board events. I removed *event* and did something like this

```
 $(document).keyup(function (e) {
     var keyId = e.keyCode; //This will work for all browser
     keyId = event.keyCode; //This will also work, but only in IE and Chrome 
 });
```

*event* is internally provided by IE and Chrome, but it is not there in Firefox.

Try this out. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If all you did is replace the parameter name "event" with the shortened "e" you haven't actually changed anything. ;-) You can use any arbitrary name to pass the event into the function.

Comment: May be I didn't explain it right. In above code (my code) I can get keyCode by e.keyCode and by event.keyCode, even though I haven't define event. This will work for IE for sure, because I just tried out my self :)

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, the way to do it is the `e.keyCode` (using the name "event" was the suggestion in another answer, but it's the same) because the event is being passed in. I didn't actually know that 'event' was available globally! New knowledge for me. ;-)